# comparing ranks for a multinomial distribution between sample and population

Tags: probability, multinomial-distribution, sample, ranking, subset

I have a known multinomial distribution of a population due to a census. I want to compare a sample with this population. I want to know the probability that the same ranking of the classes of the multinomial is observed in the sample as in the population. Example:
Assume there are 20 brands of wine. We know the market share of each brand.
What is the probability of observing the most frequent brand as a the most frequent brand in a sample AND of the second most frequent brand as the second most frequent brand in the sample and so on up to the k-most frequent brand.

Comment: What does "compating" in the title mean?  Computing, competing, comparing, counting, ... ?

Comment: I meant "comparing ranks for a multinomial distribution". Sorry for the typo. The problem should be common in survey research, but I find no reference for it. The problem is part of an analysis of a frequency attack in a cryptographic setting.